# To show the equality

Tags: elementary-set-theory

To prove :$[(A\cap X) \cup (B\cap X^{c})]^{c}=(A^{c}\cap X)\cup (B^{c}\cap X^{c}).$
I tried too much and I am getting right hand side exactly with one extra term in union which is $(A^{c} \cap B^{c}).$
Any help or hint.

Comment: Write down what you tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking the beginning of wuestenfux:
$$[(A\cap X)\cup (B\cap X^c)]^c = (A\cap X)^c \cap (B\cap X^c)^c \\
= (A^c\cup X^c) \cap (B^c\cup X) = (A^c\cap B^c)\cup (A^c\cap X)\cup (X^c\cap B^c)\cup (X^c\cap X)\\
 = (A^c\cap B^c)\cup (A^c\cap X)\cup (X^c\cap B^c)\\
= (A^c\cap B^c \cap X)\cup (A^c\cap B^c \cap X^c) \cup (A^c\cap X)\cup (X^c\cap B^c)\\
= (A^c\cap X)\cup (X^c\cap B^c).$$

The last equality is because of $(A^c\cap B^c \cap X) \subseteq (A^c\cap X)$ and $(A^c\cap B^c \cap X^c) \subseteq (B^c \cap X^c)$.

Answer (score 0):

I'd keep the rhs as it is and simplify the lhs:
$[(A\cap X)\cup (B\cap X^c)]^c = (A\cap X)^c \cap (B\cap X^c)^c = (A^c\cup X^c) \cap (B^c\cup X)$ which gives $(A^c\cap B^c)\cup (A^c\cap X)\cup (X^c\cap B^c)\cup (X^c\cap X)$ and in turn this gives $(A^c\cap B^c)\cup (A^c\cap X)\cup (X^c\cap B^c)$. The extra term doesn't vanish.

Comment: actually you can make it vanish